# Unable to reorder after layers from multiple ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayers

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I used the ArcGIS Javascript layer reordering [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/layers_dynamic_reorder.html) as template.

Initially I have 4 layers added to the map by ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer where reordering was working. Then, instead of using add lake from a table, I add 5 other layers using ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer again and pushed the layers into the first ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer with `DynamicLayerInfos.push(newDynamicLayerInfo)`.

The drag and drop list would update to include all the old + new layers. But the new layer wouldn't reorder.

I drag the new layers all the way to the top and move it around. What ended up happen was that no matter name in the list was the first four item, it would change the order of the older layers. Example:

```
old1 => old layer1
old2 => old layer2
new4 => old layer3
new3 => old layer4
```

so if I move it around this would happen

```
old1 => old layer1
new3 => old layer4
new4 => old layer3
old2 => old layer2
```

It doesn't seem to be registering the new layer in the older ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer which I push the new layers into. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Allen

```
function addProperty(){
    var propertyLayer, propertyDynLayerInfos, dynamicLayerInfo;

    // disable the "Add Property" button
    dijit.byId("property").set("disabled", true);
    dijit.byId("property").destroy();

    // show a loading icon
    //dojo.style(dojo.byId("loading"), "display", "inline-block");
    dojo.style(dojo.byId("loading"), "visibility", "visible");

    urlDyn = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer";
    propertyLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(urlDyn, { "id": "Property2" }); //only work for mapserver not featureserver
    app.map.addLayer(propertyLayer);

    var addLayerhandler = dojo.connect(
        propertyLayer, 
        "onUpdateEnd", 
        function() {
            dojo.disconnect(addLayerhandler);
            dojo.style(dojo.byId("loading"), "visibility", "hidden");

            // create a new dynamic layer info object for the property layer
            if ( ! app.hasOwnProperty("dynLyrInfos") ) {
                app.dynLyrInfos = app.map.getLayer("Kings County").createDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos();
            } 

            // add new layers
            //propertyDynLayerInfos = propertyLayer.hasOwnProperty("dynamicLayerInfos") ? propertyLayer.dynamicLayerInfos : propertyLayer.layerInfos;
            propertyDynLayerInfos = propertyLayer.createDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos();
            alert(propertyLayer + " " + propertyLayer.hasOwnProperty("dynamicLayerInfos"));
            dojo.forEach(
                propertyDynLayerInfos, 
                function(dynamicLayerInfo, i)
                {
                    app.dynLyrInfos.push(dynamicLayerInfo);
                }
            );

            app.map.getLayer("County").setDynamicLayerInfos(app.dynLyrInfos);
        }
    );
```